# Jquery dialog - button tooltip

Tags: jquery

How to set the tooltip for jquery dialog buttons ? Please see the below ...Here is no id or style classes.

```
jQuery("#dialog-form").dialog ({ 
 autoOpen: false,
  height: 600,
  width: 700,
  modal: true,
  resizable: false,
  draggable: false, 
  buttons : {
     "Search" : function() {},"edit":function()}
```

When mouse over the button or ready to click the button, message needs to showup. Please advise.

Comment: A fiddle would be helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest way would be to simply enumerate the buttons and assign the title attribute.

```
$('button').eq(0).attr('title','Delete all items');
$('button').eq(1).attr('title','Cancel');
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xVGVj/)**

Answer (score 1):

A fork of j's, except using the actual jQuery UI tooltips:
http://jsfiddle.net/Ultimate/FxHAu/

```
$(function () {
        $(document).tooltip();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I did this with jQuery 1.11.2

```
buttons: [
        {
            text: "Search",
            title: "Search Tooltip",
            click: function () {
                search();
            }
        }
    ]
```